Why does the Adblocker that I have created block stylesheets and not just ads?
I am creating an Adblocker clone using manifest 3, and for some reason whenever the ad blocker is on it removes both the ads on the site and the css stylesheet, leaving only the html file.
here is my manifest file:
{
    "name" : "Rock AdBlocker", 
    "description" : "Block all annoying ads", 
    "manifest_version" : 3,
    "version" : "0.1.0",
    "permissions" : ["declarativeNetRequest"],
    "declarative_net_request" : {
        "rule_resources" : [
            {
                "id" : "ruleset_1", 
                "enabled" : true,
                "path" : "rules.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}

and here is my rules.json file that is referenced above:
[
    {
        "id" : 1, 
        "priority" : 1, 
        "action" : {"type" : "block"}, 
        "condition" : {"urlfilter" : "*://*doubleclick.net/*"}
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 2, 
        "priority": 1, 
        "action" : {"type" : "block"}, 
        "condition" : {"urlfilter" : "*://googleadservices.com/*"}
    }
]

so what might be the issue and how to fix it? I am still new to this whole extensions stuff.


List the affected types in "resourceTypes". 2) Your urlFilter is invalid. Use "||doubleclick.net/" and "||googleadservices.com/" or better yet remove the second rule and use "requestDomains": ["doubleclick.net", "googleadservices.com"] instead of urlFilter.


what kind of resource types do I need to put in resourceTypes to block ads? I went on googleadsence to check but nothing entirely. I added the request domains one instead of url filter but the issue still persists

Probably "image","sub_frame"

Why the javascript tag here? You haven't posted any javascript code. (or any code at all. It doesn't seem to be about coding)
